# 400 vs 404 on unexpected path variable type

Tags: rest, specifications

Let's say we have the following API:

```
GET /api/colors/{color}
GET /api/integers/{number}
```

In code I expect that 'color' will match some value in enum and 'number' is an integer.

For example:

```
GET /api/colors/red
GET /api/integers/2
```

would respond with HTTP 200.

But then how should I respond to requests such as:

```
GET /api/colors/foo
GET /api/integers/bar
```

Should it be 404 because color 'foo' and integer 'bar' does not exist? Or 400 because client didn't use some agreed allowed values (enum, integer)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A resource responding with `404` might be `200` at a later moment.

For example, you query a color which is not available as of today but might be added tomorrow:

```
GET /api/colors/lightblue
```

Should respond with `404`.

Whereas a request like `/api/integers/bar` is malformed and it will be malformed in the future, so it should respond with `400`; an integer can semantically never be a string.

Sending `400` tells the client "do not query this again", the client can "remember" (cache) this answer implicitly.

`404` tells the client "right now, I don't have what you request, try again later". The client can apply caching based on heuristic or explicitly.

Comment: `/api/integers/bar` could be considered malformed by my application, but by standards it is completely valid. Is okay that different APIs have different understanding of what is malformed uri?

Comment: @Valdemaras Maybe malformed is the wrong word. It's a valid URI, but concerning the semantics of your API, it's invalid. There is no standard, just best practices. Many of the questions like yours get closed because the answer is an opinion, not a standard.

Comment: @DansFromGermany I guess you're right, that it's matter of opinion. It's just not clear from the start that there isn't any standard for it :(

Answer (score 0):

> Should it be 404 because color 'foo' and integer 'bar' does not exist?

[404](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4).

All of the 4xx status codes inform the client that there was some sort of problem with the request.  The semantic distinction is that `404` hints that there was a spelling error in the target-uri.

One of the reasons that we care: `404` is [cacheable](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.1); generic components can remember the response to the request, and save a round trip to the server if the request is repeated.